# How to alter primary key column to autoincrement in derby using eclipse

Tags: derby

I create a table and set one Integer column as a primary key.Now I want to set Auto Increment by 1 to that column.I am using this query but getting error.

```
ALTER TABLE APP.DocumentGroupCategory 
ALTER ID INTEGER NOT NULL 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1);
```

How can I alter column without drop table and create once again?

Comment: Do you mean that the column "ID" was originally created with no "GENERATED ... AS IDENTITY" clause, but now you want to add that to the "ID" column?

Comment: how to set Identity using alter